# Angular ng-repeat based off of another ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a `<select>` in my application, which is supplied data from an `ng-repeat` but each option in the select has data of it's own. Simply enough, here is the JSON payload I am working with:

```
{
    "0":{
        "name":"Mover",
        "scalar":[
            {
                "name":"Size",
                "unit":"m"
            },
            {
                "name":"Speed",
                "unit":"m/s"
            }
        ]
    },
    "1":{
        "name":"Stationary",
        "scalar":[
            {
                "name":"Size",
                "unit":"m"
            }
        ]
    },
    "2":{
        "name":"Vibrator",
        "scalar": [
            {
                "name":"Frequency",
                "unit":"hz"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I need the outer 3 names in the select, but I'd like the 'scalar' values to show up as checkboxes next to the select. It's obviously got to be dynamic, so i was curious if there was a way to do this based off of the `ng-repeat` of the select. Another reason why I am asking is because due to formatting, I'd like to place the checkboxes outside of the ng-repeat (clearly since that's in a select) so not too sure how the checkboxes would access the repeat value. Below is the `html` snippet:

```
<div id="type-selection"
    class="row ng-hide"
    ng-show="rcw.page ==='Type Selection'">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="rule-type">Type</label>
      <select id="rule-type"
          class="form-control"
          ng-model="rcw.selectedRuleType">
        <option ng-repeat="type in rcw.QueryTypes">{{type.name}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2" ng-repeat="ideally scalar in type from above^">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox"
          class="faChkSqr"
          ng-model="ideally this would be dynamically tied to scalar.name </input>
      <span></span>
      <b>{{ideally this would be scalar.name}}</b>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Just not too sure if this is possible, or if I need to handle what's selected then from there in the javascript decide what needs to be displayed? Thanks in advance!

Comment: add plnkr or fiddle.

Comment: `ng-repeat` will ONLY loo your data and instantiates a template. It will not look for the change inside your select. Add a `ng-model` on your select that will update your checkboxes

Comment: Do you mean that the `option` selected in the select ng-repeat should populate the options in the checkbox?

Comment: @erp Can you accept an answer if your issue is solved? :)

Answer (score 0):

You are storing the selection in a variable: `rcw.selectedRuleType`

```
<select id="rule-type" class="form-control" ng-model="rcw.selectedRuleType">
    <option ng-repeat="type in rcw.QueryTypes">{{type.name}}</option>
</select>
```

I guess you just have to loop over this object with your ng-repeat:

```
<div class="col-md-2" ng-repeat="scalar in rcw.selectedRuleType">
    {{scalar.name}}
</div>
```

---

As a side note, I suggest you to use [`ng-options`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) in your select:

```
<select ng-model="rcw.selectedRuleType" 
        ng-options="type as type.name in rcw.QueryTypes">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
<li ng-repeat="n in items">{{n.name}}{{n.scalar}}      
       <select ng-model="selectme" ng-options="options.name for options in n.scalar">
      <option value="">-- choose color --</option>
    </select>{{selectme}}
        </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can create checkboxes based on the selection,But not sure how we can dynamically bind model based on `scaler.name`.

We need to set the value of option as scaler of selected option.Then we should listen to change event on select field & extract the scalar value from the selected value.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.QueryTypes = [{
        "name":"Mover",
        "scalar":[
            {
                "name":"Size",
                "unit":"m"
            },
            {
                "name":"Speed",
                "unit":"m/s"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name":"Stationary",
        "scalar":[
            {
                "name":"Size",
                "unit":"m"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name":"Vibrator",
        "scalar": [
            {
                "name":"Frequency",
                "unit":"hz"
            }
        ]
    }
];
$scope.getScalarTypes=function(){
$scope.scalarTypes=JSON.parse($scope.selectedRuleType);
}



});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<div id="type-selection">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="rule-type">Type</label>
      <select id="rule-type"
          class="form-control"
          ng-model="selectedRuleType" ng-change="getScalarTypes()">
        <option ng-repeat="type in QueryTypes" value="{{type.scalar}}">{{type.name}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2" ng-repeat="scalar in scalarTypes">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox"
          class="faChkSqr"</input>
      <span></span>
      <b>{{scalar.name}}</b>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```